# custom model magento looks in Mage/...?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, model, resource-model

I try to follow this tutorial:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html

Problem is it doesn't work at all as Magento always tries to load the model from the wrong folder

Warning: include(Mage/My/Module/Model/Resource/Blogpost.php)

Here is my config.xml. The part with overwriting the success page works like a charm.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <my_module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </my_module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <my_module>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_Module</module>
                    <frontName>my_module</frontName>
                </args>
            </my_module>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <my_module>
                    <file>module.xml</file>
                </my_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Block</class>
            </my_module>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_success>My_Module_Block_Onepage_Success</onepage_success>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <models>
        <my_module>
            <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>my_module_resource</resourceModel>
        </my_module>
    </models>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<models>` node needs to be inside the `<global>` node. Like you did for the `<blocks>` node:

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Block</class>
            </my_module>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_success>My_Module_Block_Onepage_Success</onepage_success>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>my_module_resource</resourceModel>
            </my_module>
        </models>
    </global>
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed so many tutorials (that didn't point this out) I missed the forest for the trees... -.-

Answer (score 1):

Move :

```
<models>
    <my_module>
        <class>My_Module_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>my_module_resource</resourceModel>
    </my_module>
</models>
```

To, `<global>`

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <my_module>
            <class>My_Module_Block</class>
        </my_module>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_success>My_Module_Block_Onepage_Success</onepage_success>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <my_module>
            <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>my_module_resource</resourceModel>
        </my_module>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: this is similar answer as @Rahpael

Comment: @QaisarSatti: may be we are both answering at same time. It's possible, right ?? : )

Comment: 2 minute difference between these two answer but maybe possible but try to not add identical answer.

Comment: Sure, I'll.  I was trying to provide answer with code. When I posted my answer, I also see the answer of Raphael (with single line, that says move models to global). After that he edited his answer with code that makes our both's answer similar. : )